# Unable to solve this Null issue in swift 4?

Tags: swift, string, null, is-empty

I am trying to check value which I am receiving from the server, if a string is empty I am using the following condition.

```
 var line2Cvar = permanentCAddVarDictionary?["line2"] as! String
                    if line2Cvar.isEmpty {
                        line2Cvar = "---"
                    }
                    self.permanentCAddDic.setValue(line2Cvar, forKey: "line2Cvar")
```

if a string is null I am using the following condition.

```
 var line2Cvar = permanentCAddVarDictionary?["line2"]

                    if line2Cvar is NSNull {
                        line2Cvar = "----"
                    }
                    self.emergencyContactDic.setValue(line2Cvar, forKey: "line2Cvar")
```

but in my case sometimes I am getting empty and sometimes I am getting a null value. how check string is empty or null directly.

Comment: Do you want to check if a string is empty or nil in one statement?

Comment: not empty or nil i need to check empty or null

Answer (score 0):

When checking for a string in a dictionary, you have 4 possible states:

1. the string is present, and non-empty
2. the string is present, but empty
3. the key is in the dictionary, but the value isn't a string
4. the key is absent from the dictionary

You have to check each case individually.

```
let possibleString = dict[key]

if let string = possibleString as? String {
    if string.isEmpty {
        // deal with empty case
    } else {
        // deal with non-empty case
    }
} else if possibleString == nil {
    // deal with key not-present case
} else {
    // deal with value-not-string case
}
```

You can combine some checks and eliminate others, depending on the particular logic you require.  For example, if you want to treat not-present and not-a-string the same way, you can eliminate the `nil` check, and just fall-through to the final `else`.

Comment: hi @avi your answer is working as i expected way. if it is one string i can go with you answer , in my case i am having more than 50 strings how to check all the strings in simple way

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
    var isEmptyNull:Bool {

        let string = self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)

        if string == "" || string.lowercased() == "null" {
            return true
        }else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

You can check here

```
let stringvalue = ""

if stringvalue.isEmptyNull {
     print("string value is empty or null")
}else {
     print(stringvalue)
}
```

output

```
string value is empty or null
```

Comment: if its string value i can use your condition but in my case i cant guess the string would be empty or null @iParesh